# Why is my Subversion (SVN) Repositories error.log 16 GB?

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

For some reason I have a file error.log which is 16GB

In my Repositories folder on my SVN Server.

It is normal?

Why is it so big?

Can I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say delete it and them monitor it (now it is a manageable size) and figure out what's causing all the errors.
Sounds like you are talking about the Apache log, so it could be related to Apache instead of just SVN. If it is the apache log, try turning the error reporting level down in the http.conf  file.

Comment: It was set to DEBUG in the http.conf

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN Server logs all error messages to Windows Event Log starting from version 1.6. Please upgrade to the latest version if you didn't.